# How to find Windows Phone 8.1 store link in new Windows Dev Center before publishing?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, windows-10, windows-dev-center

I am going to publish a new Windows Phone 8.1 application using the new Windows Dev Center and I would like to know the Windows Phone 8.1 store link before publishing the application.

In the old Windows Phone Dev Center I was able to "guess" it using the apps GUID, but now I don't see how I can get the app's GUID, and all the new Dev Center shows me is the Windows 10 link that won't work in Windows Phone 8.1 devices.

Can someone help me find a way to figure out the app link before publishing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new application in your dashboard you should see on the left side menu a category App Management -> App identity. On the bottom of this page you have the link. This link will automatically redirect to the right WP8.1 app when opened on a WP8.1 device.

Comment: I have tried that in two devices, but in one of them it doesn't work and I don't really know why. In the other one it works exactly as you said.